# I cannot access the KeyPressed function for when i press the ESCAPE key

Tags: blackberry, netbeans, java-me

The first problem is that the addKeyListener does is redlined wherever I place it. I've looked at various different examples online but it seems that Im missing something.

here is my code:

```
import net.rim.device.api.system.KeyListener;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Keypad;

public class BBMIDLET extends javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet implements KeyListener

    public void startApp() {
    Display.init(this); 

   addKeyListener(new TestKeyPadListener());    

    }

    public class TestKeyPadListener implements KeyListener {

    public boolean keyChar(char key, int status, int time) {
        System.out.println("key: " + key);
        return false;
    }

    public boolean keyDown(int keycode, int time) {
        System.out.println("keycode: " + keycode);
        if (Keypad.key(keycode) == Keypad.KEY_ESCAPE) {
            System.out.println("Hi");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean keyUp(int keycode, int time) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    public boolean keyRepeat(int keycode, int time) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    public boolean keyStatus(int keycode, int time) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: _addKeyListener does is redlined_ does that mean code fails to compile when you add that statement?

Comment: yes, i meant to say that it is sees the line as an error.

Answer (score 1):

`addKeyListener(KeyListener l)` is not a method of `javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet` or `net.rim.device.api.system.KeyListener` and you did not declare it anywhere else in your `BBMIDLET` class so it is undefined.

Comment: You need to get or create some kind of GUI component on which you can call `addKeyListener`. I'm not experienced with mobile development but for a standard Java app that would be any component that extends [java.awt.Component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html).